# Installing opencv 3.4.2 with Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, anaconda

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04LTS:

Firstly, I couldn't install opencv from anaconda on my existing environment (base) as it kept searching for conflicts forever and then getting stuck with an empty window saying "these packages will be modified" while displaying absolutely nothing and with the only choice of pressing the "cancel" button.
I created a new virtual environment named env_opencv and was able to install opencv:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Exxr.png)

Then, I run a jupyter notebook that imports opencv:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
 ...
```

And here's what I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-31cd2c78c525> in <module>
----> 1 import cv2
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import matplotlib.patches as patches
     4 
     5 from align import AlignDlib

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

No matter what I tried, including reinstalling opencv directly from the conda prompt, I can't get past this error.

Incidentally, I was able to make it work on Windows 10 going through the Anaconda prompt and using conda. However, my Windows machine doesn't have an nVidia GPU and I can't use it for CNN training, so I really need to make it work on Ubuntu.

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't use the base environment, create a new, separate one for each project you have. Are you sure that the Python script is being run using the correct installation and packages?

Comment: I did create a different environment, please read the whole post

Comment: You did create a different environment **eventually**.

Comment: OK, I guess I'm not using proper English or you are not reading the post as you should: I had already created the new environment from the get go. What I am saying is that Anaconda is not switching between the environments from the GUI and I believe it's a BUG.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to this issue:
I activate the env_opencv environment from the command line, then I launch jupyter notebook and it works.
Maybe, there is a bug with anaconda-navigator that doesn't seem to switch environments from the GUI?